# Loading Codeigniter Library multiple times

Tags: php, codeigniter

okay, so I have two separate configs for the same library in the same controller function. The first one runs just fine, but the second does not. How can I make it so codeigniter `unsets` the first one and uses the second config.

```
// Retrieve the data from the upload
        $data = $this->upload->data();

        //Re-size the large image and re-save it
        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image'] = $this->config->item('upload_path').''.$this->aauth->get_user_id().'/'.$file_name.''.$data['file_ext'];
        $config['new_image'] = $this->config->item('upload_path').''.$this->aauth->get_user_id().'/';
        $config['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $config['master_dim'] = 'auto';
        $config['width']    = 600;
        $config['height']   = 516;

        $this->load->library('image_lib', $config);

        if ( ! $this->image_lib->resize())
        {
            echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
        }
        else
        {
            $this->image_lib->crop();
            echo 'Image Resized!';
        }

        //Create a thumbnail for the image
        $config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image'] = $this->config->item('upload_path').''.$this->aauth->get_user_id().'/'.$file_name.''.$data['file_ext'];
        $config['new_image'] = $this->config->item('upload_path').''.$this->aauth->get_user_id().'/thumbnails/';
        $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $config['width']    = 120;
        $config['height']   = 120;

        $this->load->library('image_lib', $config); 

        if ( ! $this->image_lib->resize())
        {
            echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
        }
        else
        {
            echo 'Image Thumbnail Created!';
        }
```

So it re-sizes the image and then is supposed to thumbnail an image.

Comment: It's a codeigniter library

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the initialize method provided by the [library](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/image_lib.html), so you call it instead of loading the library each time:

```
$this->load->library('image_lib');

$config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image'] = $this->config->item('upload_path').''.$this->aauth->get_user_id().'/'.$file_name.''.$data['file_ext'];
        $config['new_image'] = $this->config->item('upload_path').''.$this->aauth->get_user_id().'/';
        $config['create_thumb'] = FALSE;
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $config['master_dim'] = 'auto';
        $config['width']    = 600;
        $config['height']   = 516;

$this->image_lib->initialize($config);
```

....

```
$config['image_library'] = 'gd2';
        $config['source_image'] = $this->config->item('upload_path').''.$this->aauth->get_user_id().'/'.$file_name.''.$data['file_ext'];
        $config['new_image'] = $this->config->item('upload_path').''.$this->aauth->get_user_id().'/thumbnails/';
        $config['create_thumb'] = TRUE;
        $config['maintain_ratio'] = TRUE;
        $config['width']    = 120;
        $config['height']   = 120;

 $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
```